# How to solve "There is no extension able to load the configuration for 'monolog.http_client' "

Tags: symfony, symfony-http-client

I want to use the HttpClientInterface from symfony, so i added it in __construct like this:

```
private HttpClientInterface $client;

/**
* @param HttpClientInterface $client
*/
public function __construct(
   HttpClientInterface $client
) {
    $this->client = $client;
}
```

And just a simple request in my function:

```
$response = $this->client->request(
  'GET',
  'https://mywebsite.com/api/call/myId'
);
```

So when i try to run it i get this error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\MyService": argument "$client" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "monolog.http_client" service.
```

I tried to add it to services as it said above but i also got an error:

Like this (monolog.http_client: or http_client:)

Error: here is no extension able to load the configuration for "monolog.http_client"

So i really have no idea how to solve this problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add http_client: under framework: in services.yml

Comment: Thanks, saved my a frustrating evening

Comment: In my project /app/config/config.yml was the place where the line `http_client: ~`
after performing `composer require "symfony/http-client"` did the magic for me. This will use the default configuration of Symfony's HTTP Client.

Answer (score -1):

The component is just probably not in your vendors.
Try `php bin/console debug:container httpClient` if it can't find the service, install it with `composer require "symfony/http-client"`

Comment: I got this  Select one of the following services to display its information:
  [0] Http\Client\HttpClient
  [1] Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface